# nestjs - @Transform() not being called on @Query DTO

Tags: nestjs, class-transformer

I have an endpoint with some optional query parameters. I'm using `class-transformer`'s `@Transform()` pipe to fill it in if not existent.
But the pipe is never being called and values if not provided are empty.

```
Controller:

  @Get()
  async findAll(
    @Query() query: ActivitiesListPATRequestDto
  ) {
    ...

    return data;
  }
```

```
DTO:

export class ActivitiesListPATRequestDto extends PaginatedListRequestDto {
  @ApiPropertyOptional({ required: false, default: 'now', format: 'ISO8601' })
  @Transform(
    ({ value }: { value?: string }): string => value ?? new Date().toISOString()
  )
  @IsDateString()
  @IsOptional()
  from: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional({
    required: false,
    default: '30 days from now',
    format: 'ISO8601',
  })
  @Transform(
    ({
      value,
      obj,
    }: {
      value?: string;
      obj: ActivitiesListPATRequestDto;
    }): string =>
      value ??
      new Date(
        new Date(obj.from).getTime() + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      ).toISOString()
  )
  @IsDateString()
  @IsOptional()
  to: string;
}
```

```
global config:

  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true },
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    })
  );
```

I have tried:

- decorating controller with `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)`
- decorating controller with `@UseInterceptors(new TransformInterceptor(ActivitiesListPATRequestDto ))`
- changing `from` and `to` values from `string` to `Date`
- changing `from` and `to` to required properties

Comment: What does a sample `GET` call look like?

Comment: The idea of the transform decorators is to attach default values based on the incoming request.
If I call `GET[http://example.com/activities?from=2023-03-28T00:00:00.000Z]` I want the query object to has properties `from: 2023-03-28T00:00:00.000Z; to 2023-04-28T00:00:00.000Z;`